# picker in place of buttons

Tags: iphone

What do people do in this scenario
- Lets say you have a screen with 7-8 buttons, so instead of displaying 7 buttons in a screen which looks ugly, what other options do you receommend. Picker is one option, similar rto date picker, we can display one picker with 1 column which displays all button texts. Any recommendations on using other controls.

I have a black background, so putting a picker might not be a good option.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

UITableView could be a good option

Answer (score 0):

I think the picker is the most ridiculous looking control that Apple has ever created.  I would go with Daniel's idea and use a UITableView.  If you find that you rather like the picker functionality, just throw a UITableView into a UIScrollView.  It will look ten times better.